# How do I find where this video is recorded to?

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10, video-capture, ios-camera

Im recording from a camera to a file, but I don't know how to look for the recording to see if its working.  How do I find the recording or rewatch it afterwards?  I checked out a post about downloading the file data from the devices window, but I have no idea what to do with the resulting file.

my code:

```
class Camera: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var recordButtonLabel: UILabel!
var recording = false
var timer = Timer()
var time = 0.0
var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var sessionOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
            let videoFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

@IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!

func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
    return
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDuoCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera,AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.unspecified)
    for device in (deviceDiscoverySession?.devices)! {
        if (device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {
            do{
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device )
                if captureSession.canAddInput(input){
                    captureSession.addInput(input)
                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){
                        captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                        captureSession.startRunning()
                    }
                }
            }
            catch{
                print("Error displaying camera data")
            }
        }
    }
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    previewLayer.frame = cameraView.bounds
}

@IBAction func recordButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if recording == false {
        recordButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(Camera.processTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        recording = true

        let recordingDelegate:AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate? = self
        self.captureSession.addOutput(videoFileOutput)
        let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "filePath")
        videoFileOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: filePath as URL!, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate)

    } else if recording == true {
        self.videoFileOutput.stopRecording()
        recordButton.tintColor = UIColor(red: 22/255, green: 102/255, blue: 248/255, alpha: 1)
        timer.invalidate()
        time = 0
        recording = false
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have a look at https://www.raywenderlich.com/94404/play-record-merge-videos-ios-swift . You may put the video into the saved photos album by using `void UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(NSString *videoPath, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);`

Comment: @Lupinity - I looked at the link you sent, and while it does record and save video, it opens a new camera view to do it, and handles the save on dismissing of the view.  However, since I don't open a new view for the camera, and instead route the camera output to a view on the UI, I don't know how to adapt the code to start recording whats in the view when I press the button.

Comment: @SebastianConsidine did you get it working?